# Optional to perform an action in either cases

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a method

```
   public Single<SignatureOrder> confirmPayment(PaymentEntity entity, Identity identity, ConfirmationRequest confirmationRequest) {
        return chooseClient(entity)
                .confirmPayment(identity, entity,confirmationRequest);
    }
```

I need to do a little modification, in case of `confirmationRequest` is `null`  then call `confirmPayment(identity, entity);`

How can i say something like 
`Optional.ofNullable(confirmationRequest)` then `chooseClient(entity)` then `ifPresent` call `confirmPayment(identity, entity,confirmationRequest);` `ifNotPresent` call `confirmPayment(identity, entity);`

Signatures of `confirmPayment`

```
 public Single<SignatureOrder> confirmPayment(Identity identity, PaymentEntity entity)
 public Single<SignatureOrder> confirmPayment(Identity identity, PaymentEntity entity, ConfirmationRequest confirmationRequest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Single<SignatureOrder> confirmPayment(PaymentEntity entity, Identity identity, ConfirmationRequest confirmationRequest) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(confirmationRequest)
      .map(cr -> chooseClient(entity).confirmPayment(identity, entity, cr)
      .orElseGet(() -> chooseClient(entity).confirmPayment(identity, entity);
}
```

mapping on null returns empty, by using orElseGet if it maps to empty it would call this lambda

Comment: what is `getOrElse`?

Comment: What about `chooseClient(entity)` ?

Comment: what if now `chooseClient(entity).confirmPayment(identity, entity, cr)` returns `null`?

Comment: Melad has not specified confirmPayment could return null

Comment: This code is hardly more readable than a simple `if` statement. According to the language creators, `Optional` is not meant to be used as  replacement for `if` statements, but as the return value of methods that could return either a value or nothing instead.

Comment: There are at least two `)` missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as :

```
public Single<SignatureOrder> confirmPayment(PaymentEntity entity, Identity identity, ConfirmationRequest confirmationRequest) {
    return confirmationRequest != null ? 
            chooseClient(entity).confirmPayment(identity, entity, confirmationRequest) : 
            chooseClient(entity).confirmPayment(identity, entity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can do that without posting a question on stackoverflow, is there any way to do it in java8 style ?

Comment: @MeladEzzat Define better then. Is it performance, readability or what?

Comment: I do it as apart of my learning java8, also in my current project we are using java8 as a divine standard

Comment: @MeladEzzat then it would also be good to learn that not every `if` condition with a `null` check should be replaced with an `Optional` in use.